# Descriptor to restrict input

Tags: python, python-3.x, design-patterns, properties

We start off we the following `Person` class:

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self):
        self.moods = {
            "happy": 5,
            "angry": 5,
            "sad": 5
        }

    def updateStates(self, stateUpdates: {}):
        for mood, valChange in stateUpdates.items():
            self.moods[mood] += valChange
```

From here I implemented a restriction on what the values `self.moods` can be.
I have implemented the restriction using descriptors. But I find it distasteful.

The following works. But I don't think it is worth it because now I have to append `.__get__(instance=self, owner=None)` to `self.moods[<mood>]` whenever I need to access a mood, or `.__set__(instance=self, value=<newVal>)` whenever I want to update one. This will quickly pollute my code and make it unreadable, which is why I am not a fan of this approach.

```
class OneDigitNumericValue():    # descriptor class
    def __set_name__(self, owner, name):
        self.name = name

    def __init__(self, defaultVal=5):
        self.value = defaultVal

    def __get__(self, instance, owner) -> object:
        return self.value

    def __set__(self, instance, value) -> None:
        if not (0 < value < 9) or int(value) != int:
            raise AttributeError("The value is invalid")
        self.value = value

class Person:
    moods = {
        "happy": OneDigitNumericValue(),
        "angry": OneDigitNumericValue(),
        "sad": OneDigitNumericValue()
    }

    def updateStates(self, stateUpdates: {}):
        for mood, valChange in stateUpdates.items():
            oldVal = self.moods[mood].__get__(self, owner=None)
            self.moods[mood].__set__(self, value=oldVal + valChange)
```

Comment: This code can't ever work. Have you actually ran your provided code? `int(value) != int` is always true, you always error on any input.

Comment: Can you provide some examples on what input you expect this to work with. Because `Person().updateStates({'happy': 1})` doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

## Your solution just doesn't work

1. Your validation check always fails. Yes `int(value) != int` is always true. I don't think an instance of a class will ever be the class that it's an instance of.
2. Your mutating a class variable. The tool you're utilizing forces you to take instances, normally there's a pretty good reason.

   If we remove the previous error and run your code we can easily see, there's no point in having more than one instance of a `Player`.

   ```py
   >>> a = Person()
   >>> b = Person()
   >>> a.moods['happy'].__set__(a, 8)
   >>> b.moods['happy'].__get__(b, None)
   8  # Ok, that's not right...
   ```

I don't believe you've actually tried to code you've provided. And honestly what's the point in a single-data non-singleton class? The provided code is just untested garbage.

## You're using it wrong

If it's not evident enough that you're fighting a tool that is pure sugar. Then you're not doing it right. The instance has to keep the state of the instance, and the descriptor has to interact with a varying amount of instances to interact with *their* state correctly.

If anything of the instance's leaks out into the descriptor, or vice versa. Then you're going to have a bad, bad time.

Since descriptors are to be tied onto classes I'm making a `Mood` class. Since the descriptor needs to have a place to store data. We can define that in the `__init__` of `Mood`. To note, because you may not notice this by yourself. `self._values` can be mutated to bypass the validator. Using `self._values[mood] = value` is not how you update values, use `setattr(self, mood, value)`.

In addition to fixing `OneDigitNumericValue`, you should make it take an argument that is the validator for the function. If you need another validator it'd be better and simpler to make a simple hard to mess-up function. Rather than making lots of potentially broken descriptors.

```py
def single_digit(value):
    if 0 <= value <= 9:
        return
    raise ValueError("The value is invalid")


class Validator:
    def __init__(self, validator):
        self.validator = validator
        self.name = None

    def __set_name__(self, owner, name):
        self.name = name

    def __get__(self, instance, owner) -> object:
        return instance._values[self.name]

    def __set__(self, instance, value) -> None:
        self.validator(value)
        instance._values[self.name] = value


class Mood:
    happy = Validator(single_digit)
    angry = Validator(single_digit)
    sad = Validator(single_digit)

    def __init__(self):
        self._values = {}
        self.happy = 5
        self.angry = 5
        self.sad = 5

    def update_states(self, states):
        for mood, value in states.items():
            setattr(self, mood, value + getattr(self, mood))
```

And it actually works:

```
>>> a = Mood()
>>> b = Mood()
>>> a.happy = 3
>>> a.happy
3
>>> b.happy
5
>>> a.update_states({'happy': 3})
>>> a.happy
6
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, as per PEP8 I'd recommend you follow the [naming conventions](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#id34).

A couple of examples:

- `updateStates` -> `update_states`
- `defaultValue` -> `default_value`

I think you were headed in the right direction, but instead of overriding the `__get__` and `__set__` methods, I would just override the `__add__` method, which would allow you to reuse the updateStates method from the first snippet. The `__add__` method allows you to override the behavior of the `+` operator ([https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.**add**](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__add__)).

Instead of `int(value) != int` to check whether `value` is an integer, you should use `isinstance`, which is the preferred way to check for the type of the variable in Python3.

Below I wrote a snippet incorporating the suggestions. As you can see, I pretty much reused your code, just added the `__add__` method and the `isinstance` check.

```
class OneDigitNumericValue:
    def __init__(self, default_val=5):
        self.value = default_val

    def __add__(self, other_value):
        if not isinstance(other_value, int):
            raise AttributeError("The value is not an integer.")

        new_value = self.value + other_value

        if not (0 < new_value < 9):
            raise AttributeError("The value is not between 0 and 9.")

        return OneDigitNumericValue(new_value)


    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self.value)

class Person:
    moods = {
        "happy": OneDigitNumericValue(),
        "angry": OneDigitNumericValue(),
        "sad": OneDigitNumericValue()
    }

    def update_states(self, state_updates: {}):
        for mood, val_change in state_updates.items():
            self.moods[mood] += val_change

p = Person()
p.update_states({"happy": 1, "angry": 1})
print(p.moods)
p.update_states({"happy": 10, "angry": 1}) # error
```

Comment: Great idea, but **I don't think this a good approach**. Now, whenever you add an integer to `self.moods[mood]`, like +2, you are basically doing `self.moods[mood]+=2`. In other words, you get an unwanted (invisible) sideeffect that whenever you add an integer to `self.moods[mood]`, `self.moods[mood]` is also (invisibly) reassigned to that value. Meaning, your sixth last line `self.moods[mood] += val_change` can be rewritten as `self.moods[mood] + val_change`. This unwanted sideeffect might have consequences down the road; especially if coworkers    unknowingly adds a value to `self.moods`.

Comment: If that is the case, instead of mutating `self.value` and returning `self` from the `__add__` method you can create a new object and return it: `return OneDigitNumericValue(new_value)`. I edited the solution, to reflect this.

Comment: Actually, instead of reassigning a value to `self.value` in `__add__` , you can just return the new_value like showed here: https://pastebin.com/PYEsiCYu. If you run the code in the pastebin, you'll see it has the desired result without the unwanted sideeffect mentioned in my first comment.

Comment: Check my edited solution, I return a new object without modifying the original object. Also returning just the new_value variable, would mean that you would have integers as values in your moods dictionary, not OneDigitNumericValue objects.

Comment: Mutating classvar's just won't end well with instances. Try making an second `Person` and you'll see that they have the exact same values _all the time_.